# Angular CLI: Assets in dist, but not build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My .angular-cli.json looks like this:

```
 "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
     ...
```

I can clearly see why the assets are going only to the `dist` folder, but how do I get them in the build folder too?

Thanks!

---

**Problem solved in comment below:**

> @nick that is not true, when you run ng serve the compiled files are
>   hosted in a virtual file system in memory and served to the browser
>   via webpack-dev-server – Brocco 4 hours ago

Comment: what is build folder you are referring too?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan it's where the compiled ts files go when you do `ng serve --dev`

Comment: @nick that is not true, when you run `ng serve` the compiled files are hosted in a virtual file system in memory and served to the browser via webpack-dev-server

Comment: @Brocco you're absolutely correct, I'd know that. Problem solved! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

angular-cli is based on **ember-cli** project.
You can create a file called `.ember-cli` on same directory as of `angular-cli.json` and add `output-path` to it

```
{
   "output-path": "./build"
}
```